# Increase linux kworker thread priority?

Tags: linux, multithreading, real-time, embedded-linux, thread-priority

I have a dual core 1GHz ARM system with linux where the business application should do low-latency serial IO> <10ms response time, receive ~10byte request, send ~20byte response. After a few iterations of design refinement the results are fairly good, but there are still occasional missed deadlines.

Doing system-wide tracing with Perfetto.dev revealed the following:

- missed deadlines occur when both cores are saturated
- the application thread has elevated priority and once it becomes runnable it enters running state in <100us and performs its job within 2ms (well within spec)
- the application thread is woken up by kworker/u4:1-events_unbound (handling serial hw) and this has the same prio as other user threads
- when a deadline is missed it is the kworker that's starved (stays in runnable state, waiting for available CPU resource)

Since the CPU becomes saturated from time to time, I see no other option than to prioritize threads that have a deadline over the rest. But changing the the priority of kworker threads (renice, chrt) smells to say at least:

- they are owned by the kernel, it doesn't feel right to change their prio
- they are created and destroyed runtime, scanning them and setting prio at startup once is not viable

**What is the proper way to solve this?**

Putting more cores at work is not an option. Even when the CPU is saturated the traces show that the deadline could be easily met, if the right thing would execute and not some background activity.

--

[image]

This trace depicts a single occurrence of the issue:

- the flag indicates the timepoint where traffic arrives: 6 bytes
- at this point kworker becomes runnable, but stays in this state this for 6.7ms
- during this time multiple processes are scheduled on both cores
- when kworker eventually runs, it wakes my thread and the application code runs

Comment: Are you using RT-KERNEL?  You probably should if you have real time deadlines.  Highest priority runnable thread runs. Priorities should be applied on RMA principles.  Though only an embedded Linux user would regard 10ms as low latency.  For hard real time, you really want your OS to get out of the way.

Comment: AFAIK, kernel threads do have a higher priority by design. It tends to also be confirmed by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226578/kernel-threads-and-user-threads-priorities). Are you sure this is a task scheduling issue and not an IO scheduling one, and/or just that the IO device is already saturated? Did you check that the IO scheduler is ready to read data back and the kernel thread is not run directly after that? What is the target IO device by the way? HDD have a high latency so 10 ms too tight but Nvme SSD should clearly able to reach that.

Comment: Personally, I would use a an IO thread with a high-priority (manually set) using asynchronous IO API like io_uring for very high-performance and low latency requirements. Since I expect kernel threads to have a higher priority than the associated user thread, there should not be latency issues in such a case except if the device is saturated so the ordering of concurrent requests starts to be critical (I saw such a thing happen on HDDs but not yet on SSDs). thread communication introduces overheads but they are <1000x smaller than your target max latency.

Comment: By the way, do you have more ready user threads than available cores? If so, then the quantum of the scheduler can be an issue if some threads do quite compute-bound operations. AFAIK, the fairness is not guaranteed when timings are smaller than a quantum, even with IO-bound threads. I hope it helps.

Comment: @Clifford Plain linux kernel is used, as you wrote my deadlines are 2 orders of magnitude less than a usual realtime systems. Audio processing works with similar deadlines on consumer OSs, a few bytes of serial data processing should work as well.

Comment: @JérômeRichard These kernel worker threads run with non-realtime scheduling and 0 nice value, just like user processes, but you're right: not all kernel threads are like these. I added a screenshot of the trace, I'm certain it's a task scheduling issue. The serial traffic is 6bytes every 32ms no contention here, both cores on the other hand are 100% busy at that time. Both cores run multiple threads while the kworker is waiting and eventually runs. The core:thread ratio is around 1:100, these are mostly idle, but time to time contention happens. That's where the deadline is missed.

Comment: Audio processing works with buffering to even out timing variation, so that is not a like for like comparison.  The _latency_ may be several tens of milliseconds.  Throughput and latency are not the same thing.

Comment: Indeed. It turns out that kthreads apparently do not have always a higher priority than user threads, even for IOs, which is surprising to me. I though it was always the case. https://lwn.net/Articles/818388/ might help you.

Comment: I wonder if the priority of kthreads are really the issue here. If the kthreads would have been executed before, then AFAIK it does not guarantee that the associated user thread will be scheduled back (unless it has a higher priority than others, but I expect the associated kthread to have at least the same priority than the user thread). I think the main issue is that the user thread waiting for data to be received has the same priority than others. If all can do such an operation, then the current scheduling seem fine to me.